# Web site on IIS 7 asking for Windows authentication only when using Firefox and not Internet Explorer?

Tags: firefox, ntlm

I have a web site on IIS 7, and it asks for Windows authentication when I try to access it with Firefox, but it works fine if I use Internet Explorer.
With Internet Explorer it uses the normal form authentication. How is this possible?

Comment: please note I get the same issue for chrome and safari, pretty much any browser other then windows, I am using iis7, Digest authentication

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not have [NTLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM) enabled by default, meaning Firefox will not pass along your NT identity to the website. This is enabled by default in Internet Explorer.

You can enable it for selected sites by going to "about:config" and by editing the `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` preference.